# MySQL - query records above date and one below

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, select

In my MySQL database I have records with date of inserting (as one of column of `datetime` type).
Besides of some `where` clause constraints I want to select all records above given date (from given date to now) and exactly one record closest below given date.
Any ideas how to achieve this using MySQL in efficient way?
I thought about using count and rank, but I think it can be very inefficient.

Comment: It would help to see the structure and an example of the results you require

Comment: A union between (pseudosql) `top 1 * where date < @MinDate order by date desc` and your normal query maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe someting like this?

```
(SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mydate >= xxx)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mydate < xxx ORDER BY mydate DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: you need parenthesis around the second query, otherwise the limit and the order by will be applied to the whole union query